# Cron: Run every thursday before last Sunday of the month

Tags: shell, date, cron

I'd like to launch a cron script on the *thursday* before the last sunday of a specified month. Caveat : the last thursday is not always before the last sunday of the end of the month.

What I'd like to do is send a mail to our users on the thursday  before the last sunday of march and oktober, when daylight savings time begins and ends.

I've found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/265879/cron-job-that-runs-on-the-last-monday-of-the-month) and [here](https://sysadminspot.com/linux/cron-to-run-on-first-specified-day-of-the-month/) a similar issue & solution :

```
00 20 * 3,10 4 [ $(date +"\%m") -ne $(date -d 7days +"\%m") ] && $HOME/bin/mailstub
```

This checks if the month today is not equal to the month 7 days from now. If not equal then it's the last monday of the month.

How can I calculate 3 days before (= thursday) before the last sunday of the month?

Many thanks!

Comment: This looks like more of a Unix question.  I suggest you move it to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @W.Prins I think it's programming, because it's about how to write the `date` expressions to calculate whether we're on a particular day of the month.

Comment: Yes but bash/shell coding and cron is typically covered on unix.stackexchange.  Also please update your tags, this has nothing to do with php.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the next Sunday is in the same month as today, but the second Sunday is not:

```
00 20 * 3,10 4 [ $(date +"\%m") -eq $(date -d 3days +"\%m") ] && [ $(date +"\%m") -ne $(date -d 10days +"\%m") ] && $HOME/bin/mailstub
```